# Outside of probability theory is there something like $\mu(A \cap B) = \mu(A)\mu(B)$, and if so, does it mean anything?

Tags: measure-theory

I was reading the introduction to David Williams' book Probability with Martingales and he made a comment along the lines that probability spices up measure theory by adding the multiplication rule and independence. That got me thinking about whether, for a given measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$, $\mu(A \cap B) = \mu(A)\mu(B)$, $A, B$  $\in \mathcal{A}$ means anything special in general measure theory. Just curious. (I'm a novice so the introduce to his book is as far as I got.)

Comment: In most all mathematical literature before roughly the 1930s and 1940s, intersections of sets were called products of sets (and unions were called sums), and the notation was the same as that for numerical multiplication (i.e. juxtaposition of set symbols, the use of $\Pi$ for the intersection of a sequence of sets, etc.). However, I think this was more due to underlying set operation properties and not probability (the latter is just one of many ways in which the underlying set operation properties manifested themselves).

Comment: If $\mu$ measures probability, then: 

 $A$ and $B$ are independent events $\Rightarrow \mu(A \cap B) = \mu(A)\mu(B).$

Comment: Note that in probability $\mu(A \cap B) = \mu(A)\mu(B)$ is not a so much a property of the measure but rather of the two events $A,B$: namely being independent. If you consider a measure that has this property for all $A,B$ then the only possibilities are $\mu(A)\in\{0,1,+\infty\}$. This isn't a very interesting measure.

Comment: Seems probability does, indeed, bring something to the party! I'm good and thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, apparently. The proposition seems only to have any useful meaning in the context of probability.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article on [independence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) has possibility of three or more events and you can draw the diagram of whether the different pairs of events happened together or not.

[image]